# React Redux mapStateToProps 'props' undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to Redux and stuck in development. 
Looks like my mapStateToProps is not passing props. I am getting error "'props' is not defined  no-undef"

My code is :

```
  <div className="modal-footer">
                <label className="pull-left login_b">
                  Have an account? Login! {props.counter}
                </label>
                <input
                  onClick={this.handleSignup}
                  type="button"
                  id="btn_signup"
                  className="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                  defaultValue="Sign Up"
                />
              </div>

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    counter: state.counter
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Signup);
```

Here is my reducer:

```
import SIGNUP from "./signupType";

const initialState = {
  login: "",
  counter: 1
};
const signupReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGNUP:
      return { counter: state.counter };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default signupReducer;
```

What i am doing wrong?

**- HERE is SOME UPDATES -**

Here is my actions:

```
export const INCREMENT = "INCREMENT";
export const DECREMENT = "DECREMENT";

export const increment = () => {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT
  };
};

export const decrement = () => {
  return {
    type: DECREMENT
  };
};
```

Here is my reducer:

```
import { INCREMENT, DECREMENT } from "./../actions/counter";

export const initialState = {
  counter: 50
};
const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return state.counter + 1;
    case DECREMENT:
      return state.counter - 1;
    default:
      return state.counter;
  }
};

export default counterReducer;
```

Here is is my component:

```
<div className="btns_flx" style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn_main_prev"
                  onClick={this.props.increment}
                >
                  <img src="imglast/chevron-left.svg" alt="" />
                  Back {this.props.counter}
                </button>
                <div></div>

                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn_main_next"
                  onClick={this.props.decrement}
                >
                  Next
                </button>
              </div>

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    counter: state.counterReducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    decrement: () => dispatch(decrement()),
    increment: () => dispatch(increment())
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EnterAddress);
```

Here is interesting that in mapStateToProps i need to mention my reducer name in order state to show up, 
After that my dispatch function do not work.

How can i fix my mapDispatchToProps function?

Comment: Please, share code of `Signup` and how do you use it. Also please take a look at how are you importing `Signup` to a component where you are using it. It should be imported using default import (`inport Signup from './Signup') and not named import.

Comment: Change your ```props.counter``` to ```this.props.counter``` in ```Signup``` page

Comment: One thing you have to change `return { counter: state.counter };` to `return { ...state, counter: state.counter };`.

Comment: is your signupReducer the root reducer?

Comment: yes,  signupReducer is root reducer.